# ulimit not reflected for jenkins slave

Tags: linux, ssh, jenkins, ulimit

**Problem**

Got `java.io.IOException: Too many open files` in solr indexing through jenkins.

Did some googling and found we have to set the ulimit for the box in where we are running the job.

So set the ulimit in a linux box with spec

```
Linux x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

in both of the following fashions

1. `ulimit -n 1000000`
2. /etc/security/limits.conf

   ```
   userx soft nofile 1000000
   userx hard nofile 1000000
   ```

**Given**

1. userx is the user through which the jenkins job is being executed.
2. when doing ssh to the box as userx manually through terminal and check `ulimit -n` am getting `10000000`

**Question**

But when executing the same ulimit -n through a jenkins job, only getting 1024 which is the default.

Any advice would be much helpful?

Comment: check the init scripts for Jenkins to ensure they're not resetting the ulimit. Also, ensure Jenkins has been restarted since making the changes to limits.conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Jenkins establish a SSH connection with each of the Node/Slave as userx.

I set the ulimit, took the node offline and bring it back and I thought the problem is on the session side.

So `Disconnect`ed the whole node from the jenkins and restarted the connection with it again. 
It brought back a new session for userx and it obviously worked.

My bad that I didn't look through the logs when I took the node offline.

*Remember: Taking a jenkins node offline and bringing it back won't bring up a new SSH session.*

Answer (score 4):

Make sure pam_limits.so is enabled for su if your jenkins startup script is using "su" for user switching.

For Ubuntu Server, uncomment "session    required   pam_limits.so" line in /etc/pam.d/su file

```
sudo sed -i '/# session\s\+required\s\+pam_limits.so/ s/# *//' /etc/pam.d/su
```

Comment: Thanks @FlareCoder, my problem was bit amateur, please see my own answer. This will be definitely helpful for someone.