# ulimit not reflected for Jenkins master which is running on Red Hat

Tags: linux, ssh, jenkins, ulimit

I already saw "[ulimit not reflected for jenkins slave](https://serverfault.com/questions/436138/ulimit-not-reflected-for-jenkins-slave)" and the steps did not work for me. Please, help. I am using Jenkins on Red Hat and I have the same problem.

I set `ulimit` to `99999` and when I check the limit with command `ulimit -n` I get `99999` but from Jenkins job I get `1024`.

I have `/lib64/security/pam_limits.so` and `/lib/security/pam_limits.so`. I can't restart Jenkins. I already added

```
root             soft    nofile          99999
root             hard    nofile          99999
```

to the file `/etc/security/limits.config`.

Please, help.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what version of "redhat", what version of jenkins, how you installed it, and how you are starting it. And possibly other relevant things.

Comment: You're probably not running Jenkins as `root`; check the ulimits for user as whom jenkins runs.

Comment: @Michael Hampton RedHat version is (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga)).I donot know how it was installed but I have this information.

Jenkins.war location: /usr/lib/jenkins
Jenkins home: /opt/jenkins-home/
Jenkins log: /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log
 
Start Jenkins: sudo /sbin/service jenkins start
Stopt Jenkins: sudo /sbin/service jenkins stop

Comment: @Dan Farrell I am running jenkins as root

Comment: According [Red Hat Solution 61334](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/61334) to take effect for the change, you have to exit and re-login, which indicates that you need to restart the Jenkins service (JVM).

Comment: Run `id -a` from a jenkins job, the way you check `ulimit` and I bet it'll turn out you are not running it as root after all.